# Creating view but get error "Views SELECT contains subquery in the FROM clause"

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This is the code i am using;

```
CREATE VIEW MostBuys AS
SELECT Kundnummer, AntalBest FROM Ordrar
JOIN (SELECT OrderNr, COUNT(*) AS AntalBest
FROM OrderContent
GROUP BY OrderNr) BesAm ON BesAm.OrderNr = Ordrar.OrderNr;
```

I'm trying to count how many rows of OrderNr there is for each specific integer and then connect this with the corresponding Kundnummer. This part works by itself;

```
SELECT Kundnummer, AntalBest FROM Ordrar
JOIN (SELECT OrderNr, COUNT(*) AS AntalBest
FROM OrderContent
GROUP BY OrderNr) BesAm ON BesAm.OrderNr = Ordrar.OrderNr;
```

But i cannot create a view with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't allow subqueries in the `FROM` clause of a view.  Arggh!

You can replace this with a correlated subquery:

This is the code i am using;

```
CREATE VIEW MostBuys AS
    SELECT o.Kundnummer,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) AS AntalBest
            FROM OrderContent oc
            WHERE oc.OrderNr = o.OrderNr
           ) as AntalBest
    FROM Ordrar o
```

Comment: So the issue is that i am trying to Join with a subquery in the From clause?

Comment: @LinusLiljequist . . . As I say in the answer, the issue is that MySQL does not support subqueries in the `FROM` clause in a view.

Answer (score 1):

You could use aggregation to work around this limitation of MySQL views:

```
CREATE VIEW MostBuys AS
SELECT o.Kundnummer, COUNT(oc.OrderNr) AS AntalBest
FROM Ordrar o
LEFT JOIN OrderContent oc ON oc.OrderNr = o.OrderNr
GROUP BY o.Kundnummer
```